# WScript.Shell error "method '~' of object '~' failed"

Tags: vb6, wsh

```
public sub Main()

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strCommand = "C:/Program Files/s/schedule.exe"
objShell.Run strCommand, vbHide, True
Unload Me

end sub
```

it's supposed to run schedule.exe hidden....but program crashes with

```
Runtime error '-2147024894 (80070002)' :
method '~' of object '~' failed
```

basically i need schedule.exe to run silently without interrupting the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had a reference to `Windows Script Host Object Model` you would get this more descriptive error message:

```
Automation error
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

This might clue you that you had to quote the executable filename if it contains spaces like this:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim objShell As Object ' WshShell
    Dim strCommand As String

    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    strCommand = "C:/Program Files/7-zip/7z.exe"
    objShell.Run """" & strCommand & """", vbHide, True ' WshHide
End Sub
```

Comment: i compiled this and basically, it doesn't hide 7z.exe

Comment: Put this in a separate project in `Form1` and call it from `Form_Load` event. Just tested it and it does spawn 7-zip and does hide the console.

Comment: Why not just this? `Shell "C:\Program Files\s\schedule.exe", vbHide`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use WScript: just use the [Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242087(VS.60).aspx) function with the vbHide argument.

```
Shell "C:\Program Files\s\schedule.exe", vbHide
```

Comment: I think OP wants to wait for the shelled process to complete.