# Visual Basic 6.0 takes minutes to open on Windows 10

Tags: vb6, windows-10

I'm working with Visual Basic 6.0 SP6. Many months ago I could make it run on Windows 10. My problem now is that every time I start Visual Basic, it takes too much time to open. I see the splash window:

[image: 2]

but it takes more or less five minutes to open.

After five minutes or more, I have Visual Basic open but with the following error message:

> Method '~' of object '~' failed [image: 1]

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Are there any add-ins that might be causing trouble?

Comment: VB6 is no longer supported. Any security flaws in the libraries will never be patched. It's time to move on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“Method '~' of object '~' failed” on starting VB6 IDE](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8573710/11683)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn VB6 is still "supported" to run by MS but there are no fixes, updates, patches etc. VB6 control vendors have definitely moved on after 12 years as there is no money to be made supporting a 20 year old product

Comment: @Carlos the `Method '~' of object '~' failed` was the generic `I tried to load something and failed but I don't know why` message. *Maybe* you'll find something in Event Viewer. A career change would be a better option

Comment: @Carlos you should opt for a different development environment like Visual Studio 2015 Community. For some maintenance of old VB6 code I have a Windows 10 PC + Oracle VM VirtualBox + Windows Vista Ultimate 32bit + Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 - just my two coins.

Comment: Try reinstalling VB6 and any third party controls. Later builds of 10 didn't play as nice with respect to installing VB6 as earlier ones from what I've read.

Comment: The VB6 **runtime** is [fully supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms788708.aspx): it ships as part of Windows. The VB6 **IDE** is [not supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vstudio/ms788708.aspx) by Microsoft although they have tested it on Windows 7 and 8 32-bit to "understand and mitigate (if appropriate) compatibility issues". However many people still use the VB6 IDE:  "making money", if you like. Why? Because they have valuable existing code and [it's not easy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6-migration) to migrate that code to a more modern platform.

Comment: Many thanks. I have already tried to reinstall everything but I'm still having the issue with the big delay opening the vb6. At least, per now, the "Method..." is not arising. I'm still migrating my old code to vb.net but it takes time. Best regards

Comment: See if this issue is your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644132/vb6-ide-slowness-and-vbkeysave5-in-the-registry. We have seen this occur on Windows 10. (Not saying it is necessarily DUE TO Windows 10)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB6 IDE Slowness and 'VBKeySave5' in the Registry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644132/vb6-ide-slowness-and-vbkeysave5-in-the-registry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution for my problem is under:
[VB6 IDE Slowness and 'VBKeySave5' in the Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644132/vb6-ide-slowness-and-vbkeysave5-in-the-registry)

I have deleted everything under vbkeysave5 and now vb6 opens very fast.

Comment: Instead of answering the question: Simply marking it as a duplicate (The flag button below your post), you can refer users to that post.